# Why there is no switching between the process

Tags: c, linux, gcc, process, fork

I have the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    pid_t pid, ppid;
    printf("Hello World1\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {

        printf("I am the child\n");
        printf("The PID of child is %d\n",getpid());
        printf("The PID of parent of child is %d\n",getppid());
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        printf("The PID of parent is %d\n",getpid());
        printf("The PID of parent of parent is %d\n",getppid());        

        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is parent runs forever without switching to child process. In this case why there is no switch to child process?

Comment: Are you certain that the child never runs? It'd be really easy to miss its output, given how much the parent will be printing (and how quickly).

Comment: redirected the o/p to some text file and searched for child. But couldn't find child

Comment: How much of the output did you search through? There's a lot of it (an infinite amount, even!), and there will likely be a *lot* of output from the parent before you see any from the child.

Comment: Are you perhaps running your program in a virtualized environment, like ideone? A VM may not provide the proper hardware abstractions for Linux to properly do preemption. Your program works fine in my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the parent should wait for the child to finish, so that the child's process entry is properly reaped.

```
waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
```

To see if the child ever gets to run with your infinite loop. run the program and `grep` for `child`:

```
./a.out | grep child
```

Comment: Yes I understand waitpid puts parent in a wait. But i am studying about the behavior of processes. I couldn't understand why there is no switching to child process, when both of them are in a infinite loop.

Comment: Only the parent is in an infinite loop.  The child ends right away.